# Label(text) at the bottom side of image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a custom build widget for grid view, in which i am either sending Icon or image to display along with Text (label). Now when i send icon i can display the test below icon, but when i am trying image i am not sure if the below approach is correct to display text or not, i am trying to put EdgeInsets in the container. I think it might fail due to pixel overload, but in my emulator, it seems to be fine.. Is there any better option for this scenario or the approach I am following is ok?

```
if (image != null) ...[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:150.0),
                    ),
                   ] else ...[
                    child  ?? Container(),
                   ],
                  Text('$label',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: AppColors.lightBlue,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),),
```

[image]

Comment: You want the text to come at the bottom, without using `EdgeInsets`, right?

Comment: Yes.. because in EdgeInsets i am providing top:150.0 , that will cause issue on devices with different size i feel.

Comment: Hey Akshay, check out my answer and let me know how it goes for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am getting your problem well, then the solution is to use [Alignment Class Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment-class.html), in the `Container`. What this will do, is it allows the `child` of the `Container` to be aligned the way we want to align it. Since your requirement is to align the text at the bottom center, hence we would use the Alignment property, `Alignment.bottomCenter`.

**Please Note:** This will tell you how to align the content which will not be disturbed as per the device size, with a background image

**SOLUTION 1 [EFFICIENT]**

```
Container(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3, // ignore this, cos I am giving height to the container
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5, // ignore this, cos I am giving width to the container
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
         image: NetworkImage('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0c/96/b1/0c96b19dc89ffdaa7ff737cfc04a095f.png')
      )
   ),
   alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, // This aligns the child of the container
   child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0), //some spacing to the child from bottom
      child: Text('Hello', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
   )
)
```

**The output would look like this now:**

[image: Resultant Image]

You can check this piece of code in any of the device, and it will show up just fine.

**SOLUTION 2 [NOT RECOMMENDED]**

> Now, if you really want the margin, there is a cleaner way to do it, and that is using **MediaQuery**, as you can see in the above code also for giving out height and width.

Now, the question arises, what `MediaQuery` is, you can find it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html), or in a simpler statement, it takes care of the size of the device. Now, whenever, we are concerned about the size of the device with the content alignment, we can use MediaQuery, and what it does, is **it will adjust the margin/height/width/padding etc according to the Device size, and will look the same everywhere**

How we can do that, I will just use your code only, and since you want **the text to come at the bottom with the use of margin**. Here, how you can do that

```
Container(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: NetworkImage('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0c/96/b1/0c96b19dc89ffdaa7ff737cfc04a095f.png')
      )
   ),
   child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25),
      child: Text('Hello', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
   )
)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Solution 2 Result]

`MediaQuery.of(context).size.height = device height`, and when we multiply, it does the math according to the device, and align the content. Similarly for `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width= device width`

I would suggest **SOLUTION 1** only, since it is clean, and would not let you do a lot in `nested child`. I hope that clears your doubt. Let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: Cool... Thanks @Alok.

Comment: Happy to help @Akshay :)